# C++ API and PInvoke in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, unmanaged, unmarshalling

I got the "System.AccessViolationException" when I am trying to call the method from C++ API. In resultXML_out I got properly formated XML with data returned as exepted but the exception is raised (exactly on this method) and cannot handle this even with try catch block. I assume that I should declare somehow the memory for resultXML_out but I don't know how to do this.

Here is C++ API method declaration:

```
SW_ErrCode  SW_GetMyUserInfo (SW_LoginID lh, SW_XML *resultXML_out)
```

Declaration of SW_XML:

```
const char * SW_XML
```

Here is my code:

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SW_LoginID
    {
        public int loginId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SW_XML
    {
        public string xml;
    }

    [DllImport("sw_api.dll")]
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute]
    public static extern SW_ErrCode SW_GetMyUserInfo(SW_LoginID sh, out SW_XML resultXML_out);
```

And here is the call of this method:

```
    SW_XML resultXML_out = new SW_XML();
    resultXML_out.xml = "";
    SW_ErrCode d = SW_GetMyUserInfo(login, out resultXML_out);
```

In API I found also such a method. But I don't know how to properly use it (or even if it is necessary):

```
char* SW_AllocateString (unsigned size)
```

But after I passed e.g. 1000 the program terminates without even an exception... Here is description of this function in API Documentation:

> Allocate a string.
>
> Returns a string allocated by the API

Comment: what is the declaration of struct SW_XML in native C++?

Comment: Declaration of SW_XML: const char * SW_XML

Comment: I'm confused. You're maping a C# struct to a native C++ char*? That's not going to work. What is the declaration of function SW_GetMyUserInfo in C++?

Comment: How should I declare SW_XML properly? I used similar solution in other methods and it seems to work properly. But there I had something like that: `SW_ErrCode  SW_Connect (const char *server, int timeout, void *tag, SW_SessionID *sh_out)` and in C# `public static extern SW_ErrCode SW_Connect(string server, int timeout, IntPtr tag, out SW_SessionID sh_out);`.

Comment: Please check this:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Matt I tried to add the attribute "UnmanagedType" with every possible configuration and the result is that program terminates when calling the method or I got the same AccessViolationException. David do you mean C++ code?

Comment: @Kamil you need to prefix usernames with the @ symbol for us to be notified

Comment: Your current code calls CoTaskMemFree on the `char*` that is returned. That won't end well. Your next step is to understand the unmanaged memory allocation. Who allocates and owns the memory?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan could you be more specific? I am really confused.